# Can exactly the same verb be included twice in one sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I want to write a sentence:

> I have been working with clients and have been performing analysis.

The sentence is a little longer but it doesn't really matter. I don't understand if it is  alright to use *have been* twice, before each verb? Or maybe I need to use *have been* only once? Or maybe both of these options are wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, but "I have been working with clients and performing analysis" would be more standard.

Comment: Repetition can be powerful rhetoric device if used properly. From a standpoint of grammaticality you can do what you want, this is more about style.

Comment: If your goal is to get the idea across succinctly and effectively, you'll probably want to omit the repetition.

Comment: "We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills . . ."

Answer (score -1):

It should be grammatically correct. How about trying

I have been working with clients and performing analysis (as in a comment above), or

I have been working with clients and have *also* been performing analysis.